# How do you configure pry for vim-like movements?

Tags: vim, vi, pry

If you put the following in your `.bashrc` file:

```
set -o vi
```

then you can use vim-like movements. How can I do that in `pry`?

Comment: https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/FAQ#readline

Comment: this seems like it's emacs-like movements, am I missing something?

Comment: The vi-like bindings in bash are provided by readline. If you manage to use readline in pry, you'll get those vi-like bindings.